# java windows 8 file read write permissions

Tags: java, windows, permissions, java-native-interface

We have a Java-JNI application that runs fine on Windows XP, and Windows 7.

When I try to run it on Windows 8 I basically get a cannot create file error.

If I point the file to be created in the `Users/documents` folder the application works. 
If I point the file to be created in a `C:\Tests folder` or the `Program Files (X86)/application` folder it fails.

Similarly If I try to shell an application from the `Program Files (X86)/application` folder it fails.

It seems that using java on Windows 8 or Windows 8.1 has some file/folder creation restrictions.

Any suggestions. We do not want to migrate the entire application to a users folder at this time.

Thanks, Don

Comment: `Program Files` should not be writable in Windows 7 either (unless you're running as admin with UAC disabled). `C:\Tests` would entirely depend on what permissions there are on the directory.

Comment: What is the exact error? Can you show the full stack trace?

Comment: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7b3ada32-181d-4c55-9259-ee44f5f83b82/cant-write-to-program-files-folder

Comment: This is a legacy app. Iwe are aware of the non convention issues. It runs fine under Windows 7. We are hoping that there is a security work around with the java or the OS. There are two errors. The first is a file creation error with the program files application folder. The second is a cannot start application when trying to shell from with a windows mfc jni DLL. The exact same code works in both cases.

Comment: One more piece if information. We have a wrapper app to test the DLL and it works fine in both windows 7 and 8. There must be something with regards to the java JVM. I am stumped on this one.

Comment: I started to focus on the spawning of the external application within the JNI DLL. Looks like I am getting a errno = 22 (invalid argument). Well I have tried all combinations. So far the JNI DLL runs fine on windows 7 and give the error code 22 on a windows 8 machine. I have diabled the antivirus and opened up permissions. No luck. Any suggestions on what to try next???